# Spring 3: Making the web-application accept null parameter for multipartfile argument

Tags: spring-mvc, exchangewebservices, multipartform-data

Currently, when the file parameter is `null` or empty in the form, the web application throws an error. I have even checked for the case when file is empty but it doesn’t seem to work. Does anyone know how to check for the case when the filename field in the form is empty and not throw an error in the web app?

I am using the following code for controller. As you can see I accept a Multi-part file parameter, which is the file uploaded in the form.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/attachment", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String sendAttachment(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authHeader,                @RequestParam("to") String to,@RequestParam("cc") String cc,@RequestParam("bcc") String     bcc,@RequestParam("subject") String subject,@RequestParam("body") String body,   @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile  file,@RequestParam("filename") String  filename) {

. . .

//here i check if the file is empty...if not empty, then only attach it in the      message. 

if(!file.isEmpty())
{
    msg.getAttachments().addFileAttachment(filename,file.getBytes());
}

. . .
```

The php file I am using to call this web service is as follows:

Following is the form post parameters sent to the web service with empty file param

```
$params = array(
            'to' => null,
            'cc' => null,

            'bcc' => "sanjaygir@gmail.com",
            'subject' => "hola sanjayg",
            'body' => "just testing message service",           

            'filename'=> "",
            'file'=>""
        );
```

I have also tried using null:

```
$params = array(
            'to' => null,
            'cc' => null,

            'bcc' => "sanjaygir@gmail.com",
            'subject' => "hola sanjayg",
            'body' => "just testing message service",           

            'filename'=> null,
            'file'=>null
        );
```

Still it throws 500 error in the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile  file` to `@RequestParam(value = "file", required=false) MultipartFile  file`